# Fastapi model having id conflicts when data is entered through the database using sql

Tags: python, model, fastapi

I have a fastapi app set up that is connecting to a PostgreSQL database. It has been working fine until one of the tables was populated through the backend by using sql to insert data. What is happening is my app is not recognizing that the id has already been taken.

For example. If the last record entered through the app had an id of 10 and I entered 10 records with the ids 11-21 then when I try to enter data through the app again it tries to use the id 11. It throws and error and I need to re-enter the data and it then used 12. It keeps incrementing like this until it reached an id that is not already taken.

Now I know I could just enter data through the backend using very high ids like 1000000. But I was wondering if there is a way to tell the app which id I stopped on so it can just continue with where I left off.

Or is there any other solutions. Thanks in advance.

This is the employee model

```
class Employees(Base):
    __tablename__ = "employees"
    employee_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name= Column(String)
    birth_date = Column(Date)
    entry_date = Column(Date)
    nic_number = Column(Integer)
    record_entered_by = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    active = Column(Boolean, default=True)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name +" "+ self.last_name
```

This is how the employees are added to the database.

```
@app.post("/index")
async def add_user(request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db), fname: str = Form(), lname: str = Form(),
        dob: date = Form(), edate: date = Form(), nic: int = Form()):
    
    employee = models.Employees(first_name=fname,
                            last_name=lname,
                            birth_date=dob,
                            entry_date=edate,
                            nic_number=nic)
    db.add(employee)
    db.commit()
    return RedirectResponse(url="/index", status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER)
```

```
                                <form action="/index" method="POST">
                                    <!--Add Employee Table-->
                                    <label class="form-label" for="nic">NIC Number:</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="number" id="nic" name="nic" placeholder="Enter NIC"><br>

                                    <label class="form-label" for="fname">First name:</label><br>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name"><br>
        
                                    <label class="form-label"  for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name"><br>

        
                                    <label class="form-label" for="dob">Date of birth:</label><br>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="date" id="dob" name="dob" placeholder="DOB"><br>
        
                                    <label class="form-label" for="edate">Date of entry to the public service:</label><br>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="date" id="edate" name="edate" placeholder="Date of entry to the public service"><br>
        
        
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add">
                                    <br>
                                </form>
```

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing some code. What does the table look like? How are you entering data, both in the application and manually?

Comment: Sorry I updated the code to show the employee modal and how they are added to the database.